# Negate a predicate in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Let say i have a predicate `is_foo?/1` in Elixir
I want to use it in a function taking a predicate as an argument, but negated.
Is there a way in Elixir to do that simply ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&(!is_foo? &1)` should do it.

Or if you prefer the long form, `fn x -> !is_foo? x end`

Comment: Thank you ! 
So far i think that Elixir is harder than JS and less powerful than Haskel on the functionnal front, i hope i'm wrong and i will continue my journey to explore it.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. It's more highly scalable and fault tolerant than node.js or Ruby because of the power of the Erlang VM. It's not strongly typed like Haskel, but I don't really know what you mean by saying it's less powerful.

Comment: On the functionnal front, outside of immutability (which you can get with a library with JS), i don't understand what it brings over JS. For example, i have been disapointed to see that curying must be done manually (and it's relatively hard to do) in Elixir .

Comment: You use Elixir for its fault tolerance, distribution story, and if you think interprocess communication might be the easiest way to abstract your application. Some of us think this is a good fit for modern soft real time web applications, for example. It's good for control plane software. Elixir will probably not beat JS when it comes to easy sequential programs, nor Haskell for expressive power. If your main interest is purely the functional aspect, Haskell, Clojure, Ocaml, etc. might be more appealing. Elixir is awesome for making the benefits of Erlang's VM more pleasant and practical.